# how can I check the available functions in code blocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

when I program in java using Netbeans I can see the available functions by pressing "." after a variable.
for example:
string s;
s.    (charAt(),concat(),contains(),etc)

is there any way to do the same in code blocks?

Comment: [Code completion plugin, might be it works](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Code_Completion_plugin)

Comment: no, I have that but it does not show the available functions, one example is if I type "." after any string in netbeans, it will show a list of the available functions (.concat(), .charAt, etc)

Comment: what vession do you use?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called *code completion*. Unfortunately, C++ is much more complex than Java due to macros, templates, operator overloading, `const`, complicated lookup rules and other things; those things tend to confuse IDEs a lot. I've never seen an IDE which understood C++ code as well as an actual compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **'codeblocks-16.01'** and its giving me the available functions list automatically by pressing "." after variable. You can also use **'Ctrl + Space'** key if the available functions list is not shown automatically. Please check the attached screenshot and its working for me with **'Windows 8.1'**.

*Update*: Make sure that **'code completion'** option is enable.

> Settings -> Editor -> Editor settings -> Code completion

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

---

[image]

---

**Also make sure:**
Setting > Editor > code completion

[image]

---

**If still does not work search for Plugins on the main site**
**if you are on UNIX-like machine like Ubuntu you can**
`sudo apt-cache search codeblocks`

```
libpath-dispatcher-perl - flexible and extensible dispatcher module
libcodeblocks0 - Code::Blocks shared libraries
codeblocks - Code::Blocks integrated development environment (IDE)
codeblocks-dbg - Code::Blocks debugging libraries
libwxsmithlib0 - wxSmith shared library (Code::Blocks plugin for RAD GUI editing)
codeblocks-contrib - contrib plugins for Code::Blocks IDE
codeblocks-dev - Code::Blocks development libraries (SDK)
codeblocks-contrib-dbg - Debugging libraries for the Code::Blocks contrib plugins
wxsmith-dev - wxSmith development files (libraries)
codeblocks-common - common files for Code::Blocks IDE
codeblocks-contrib-common - common files for the contrib plugins for Code::Blocks IDE
codeblocks-headers - Code::Blocks development headers (SDK)
wxsmith-headers - wxSmith development files (headers)
codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers - Code::Blocks development headers for wxContribItems
codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 - Code::Blocks shared libraries for wxContribItems
codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev - Code::Blocks development libraries for wxContribItems
```

**And install what you want**